# PyTorch: Using a target size (torch.Size([1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([1, 1]))

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I am new to PyTorch and working on the implementation of recommender systems.

I obtained my models from here:
https://blog.fastforwardlabs.com/2018/04/10/pytorch-for-recommenders-101.html

Following the instructions from the website, i feed the DenseNet model exactly the same way as the MatrixFactorization model.

models.py:

```
class MatrixFactorization(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, n_users, n_items, n_factors=20):
    super(MatrixFactorization, self).__init__()
    # create user embeddings
    self.user_factors = nn.Embedding(n_users, n_factors,
                                     sparse=True)
    # create item embeddings
    self.item_factors = nn.Embedding(n_items, n_factors,
                                     sparse=True)

def forward(self, user, item):
    # matrix multiplication
    prediction = (self.user_factors(user) * self.item_factors(item)).sum(1)
    # test
    return F.hardsigmoid(prediction)

def predict(self, user, item):
    return self.forward(user, item)


class DenseNet(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, n_users, n_items, n_factors, h1=128, d_out=1):
    """
    Simple Feedforward with Embeddings
    """
    super(DenseNet, self).__init__()
    # user and item embedding layers
    self.user_factors = torch.nn.Embedding(n_users, n_factors,
                                           sparse=True)
    self.item_factors = torch.nn.Embedding(n_items, n_factors,
                                           sparse=True)
    # linear layers
    self.linear1 = torch.nn.Linear(n_factors*2, h1)
    self.linear2 = torch.nn.Linear(h1, d_out)

def forward(self, users, items):
    users_embedding = self.user_factors(users)
    items_embedding = self.item_factors(items)
    # concatenate user and item embeddings to form input
    x = torch.cat([users_embedding, items_embedding], 1)
    h1_relu = F.relu(self.linear1(x))
    output_scores = self.linear2(h1_relu)
    return output_scores

def predict(self, users, items):
    # return the score
    output_scores = self.forward(users, items)
    return output_scores
```

training of densenet:

```
    index = 0       
    model.train()

for user, item in zip(users, items):
    # get user, item and rating data
    # rating = Variable(torch.FloatTensor([ratings[user, item]]))
    rating = normalize(rating_values[index])
    rating = Variable(torch.FloatTensor([rating]))
    user = Variable(torch.LongTensor([int(user)]))
    item = Variable(torch.LongTensor([int(item)]))

    index += 1
    # predict
    prediction = model.predict(user, item)
    loss = loss_fn(prediction, rating)


    optimizer.zero_grad()
    # backpropagate
    loss.backward()

    # update weights
    optimizer.step()
```

Although i receive an output i get the UserWarning:

```
    AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py:446: UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([1, 1])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
  return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
```

I thought this model takes the same input (tensor of user and item id for each user) as the mf model which works for me. What is wrong with the inputs? Which line produces this error?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error message, it's a warning about the shapes of tensors passed to `nn.MSELoss`.

Provided that you feed each model with a 1D tensor of shape `(n,)`. The only difference is that `MatrixFactorization` will return a 1D tensor (of shape `(n,)`, while `DenseNet` will return a 2D tensor: shape `(n, 1)`. To remove the extra dimension you could broadcast to shape `(-1,)` or just [`squeeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.squeeze.html*) all dimensions:

```
loss = loss_fn(prediction.squeeze(), rating)
```

---

Other things to point out:

- Call `self` instead of `self.forward`
- Don't use [`Variable`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated) as it's deprecated